# Textbox formatting string spaces wrongly

Tags: vb.net, textbox, whitespace, spacing

I have been messing around with this and just can't figure it out, I have data which I'm retrieving and then basically I am outputting to a form for the user to read etc.

When I get the text/data and write it to the textbox though it formats very strange, not how it looks when written on the console or copy and pasted to notepad etc.

I'm adding the text to a stringbuilder using `appendline`, now in the picture below when I `console.writeline` the `stringbuilder` it comes out just as it should and written, this is the **right** hand side of the picture. But then when I add the `stringbuilder` to the textbox on my form it goes all wrongly spaced as seen on the **left** hand side of the picture

[image]

Why is this happening? Now when I say select all the wrongly looking spaced text from the textbox then copy and paste into the likes of notepad, it looks perfect and identical to the right hand side. So it seems to have all the spacing but some reason the textbox is showing the spaces very strange. All the black is just product names/codes so just blacked it out so please ignore.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) for the textbox, `Consolas` for example.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! @MatSnow

Comment: Courier New is the font that have any char quite the same as space even blank. You should use Courier New

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) for the `TextBox`, as the input seems to be formatted by spaces.

Examples of monospaced fonts are `Consolas` or [`Courier New`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/courier-new) as stated in comments.